# PhantomJS and FabricJS won't convert Canvas to SVG when PNG exists

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, phantomjs, fabricjs

I have code I am running with PhantomJS, using FabricJS. It creates a HTML5 Canvas with elements, then creates an `SVG` using that Canvas. This works well in all cases except when the Canvas uses a `PNG` image. This issue does not exist if the Canvas is using an `SVG` image. Instead of generating the correct `SVG` output, it outputs an empty `SVG`, like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="902" height="542" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.5.0</desc><defs></defs></svg>
```

Expected is something along the lines of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="902" height="542" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.5.0</desc><defs></defs><g transform="translate(451 271)">
<image xlink:href="http://test2.holmescp.com/media/pdp/images/filename1446564883.png" x="-451" y="-271" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="902" height="542" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g></svg>
```

This is the most relevant parts of my code. I will post more if requested.

```
var pdc = PDC();
PDCExport = {

    // Lots of functions removed here because of irrelevance to question

    downloadSVG: function() {
        var self = this,
            canvasSvg = pdc.setCurrentCanvas(self.getActiveCanvas()).canvas.toSVG();
            return canvasSvg;
    }
}
// init function
PDCExport.init();
// Create SVG
console.log(PDCExport.downloadSVG());
```

If I paste that in Chrome Inspect Console, I get the empty SVG, but if I replace the last line with this.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log(PDCExport.downloadSVG());
}, 3000);
```

It outputs the full SVG, working in console, but still failing in PhantomJS.

I see from [setTimeout in Phantom.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950627/settimeout-in-phantom-js) that setTimeout doesn't exactly work in PhantomJS, at leaste inside of page.evaluate, which I think is what I need here.[phantomjs not waiting for "full" page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340038/phantomjs-not-waiting-for-full-page-load) and [Why PhantomJS render page use window.setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028032/why-phantomjs-render-page-use-window-settimeout) seems to suggest PhantomJS should be able to handle setTimeout inside page.evaluate.

I've tried to use [how we can use evaluateAsync in phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474525/how-we-can-use-evaluateasync-in-phantomjs) but no success on a better result.

I have tried a separate evaluate as well, but seems that it doesn't retain memory of previous evaluation.

```
    return setTimeout(function(){ 
      return result = page.evaluate(function() {
        return PDCExport.downloadSVG() + '|' + 'test';
      });
    }, 3000);
```

I have also attempted a manual setTimeout like so

```
var start_wait = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var wait_time = 3;
var end_wait = start_wait + wait_time;
while (new Date().getTime() / 1000 < end_wait)
{
}
return PDCExport.downloadSVG() + '|' + 'test';
```

None of this has worked. I will give more of the code if required, but my question is essentially this.

How do I get PhantomJS to wait inside a `page.evaluate`?